# What happens if $(f_1\otimes g_1)(u_1 \otimes v_1) = (f_2 \otimes g_2)(u_2 \otimes v_2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Prove that $\lambda$ is injective.

Here is the definition of the linear map $\lambda$:

Let $f: U \to U'$ and $g: V \to V'$ be linear maps. We define their tensor product $f \otimes g: U \otimes V \to U' \otimes V'$ by

$$(f \otimes g)( u \otimes v) = f(u) \otimes g(v)$$ for all $u \in U$ and $v \in V.$ This gives rise to a linear map

$\lambda: \operatorname{Hom}(U, U') \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(V, V') \to \operatorname{Hom}(V \otimes U, U' \otimes V')$ defined by $$(\lambda (f \otimes g))(v \otimes u) = f(u) \otimes g(v).$$

1- what is the name of this map $\lambda$ in literature?

**my attempt:**

Assume that $$(\lambda (f_1 \otimes g_1))(v_1 \otimes u_1) = (\lambda (f_2 \otimes g_2))(v_2 \otimes u_2) \quad \quad \quad (1)$$ but then what should I get? Should I get that $f_1 \cong f_2, g_1 \cong g_2$ and $v_1 = v_2$ and $u_1 = u_2$? If so how can I fulfill this?

Now, by definition of $\lambda,$ from $(1)$ we get that:

$$f_1(u_1) \otimes g_1(v_1) = f_2(u_2) \otimes g_2(v_2) \quad \quad \quad (2)$$

But then how can I complete this? what property of tensor product I should use to get what I want?

Now, by definition of tensor product of two linear functions given above we will get from $(2)$ that:

$$(f_1\otimes g_1)(u_1 \otimes v_1) = (f_2 \otimes g_2)(u_2 \otimes v_2) \quad \quad \quad (3)$$

**But then what?**

What if I want to prove that the kernel is zero instead?

Comment: What kind of objects are these? Vector spaces? Modules over some general ring? And what's up with the hopf algebra or quantum groups tags?

Comment: @Thorgott they are vector spaces and that exercise is from a quantum groups book that prepare us for Hopf Algebras

Comment: Your definition of $\lambda$ is wrong. The codomain should be $\text{Hom}(U \otimes V,U’ \otimes V’)$, and instead of $v \otimes u$ it should be $u \otimes v$. Also, in order to prove that $\lambda$ is injective, we need to start with two elements $z_1$ and $z_2$ of the domain such that $\lambda(z_1) = \lambda(z_2)$. An arbitrary element of the domain is a finite sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes g_i$, where $f_i \in \text{Hom}(U,U’)$ and $g_i \in \text{Hom}(V,V’)$. Unfortunately, $\lambda$ is not injective in the infinite dimensional case, so try to find some counterexample.

Comment: @azif00 the author has a line specifically about this switch and he said he will clarify it in a later chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elementary way of seeing this when $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional is the following. Let $u_i$ be a basis for $U$, and $u_j’$ a basis for $U’$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(U,U’)$ has basis $E_{ji}$ sending $u_i\mapsto u’_j$, and the other basis vectors for $U$ to zero. Similarly for $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V’)$, having basis $F_{qp}\colon v_p\mapsto v’_q$. Thus $\mathrm{Hom}(U,U’)\otimes\mathrm{Hom}(V,V’)$ has basis $E_{ji}\otimes F_{qp}$.

Next, $U\otimes V$ has basis $u_i\otimes v_p$, and $U’\otimes V’$ has basis $u’_j\otimes v’_q$, and so $\mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V,U’\otimes V’)$ has basis $G_{jq,ip}$, sending $u_i\otimes v_p\mapsto u’_j\otimes v’_q$.

Finally, $\lambda$ sends $E_{ji}\otimes F_{qp}\mapsto G_{jq,ip}$, and so we have an isomorphism.

---

Edit.

For infinite dimensional modules the result is more subtle, and the key concept here is that of a Mittag-Leffler module. For a commutative ring $R$, an $R$-module $M$ is Mittag-Leffler if and only if, for every family of $R$-modules $N_p$ the map
$$ M\otimes_R\prod N_p \to \prod(M\otimes_RN_p) $$
is injective.

We claim that every free module is Mittag-Leffler. Take $M=R^{(I)}$ and a family $N_p$. The map
$$ M\otimes\prod N_p \to \prod(M\otimes N_p) $$
sends $m\otimes(n_p)$ to $(m\otimes n_p)$. Suppose we have an element $x$ in the kernel, and write it using a basis $e_i$ for $M$ as
$$ x = \sum_{j\in J}e_j\otimes(n_{p,j}) $$
for some finite subset $J$ of $I$. Then $\sum_je_j\otimes n_{p,j}=0$ for all $p$, so $n_{p,j}=0$ for all $p,j$, so $(n_{p,j})=0$ for all $j$, so $x=0$.

In our situation, when $R=K$ is a field, we can write $U\cong K^{(I)}$, in which case $\mathrm{Hom}(U,U’)\cong\prod_IU’$. Similarly $V\cong K^{(P)}$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V’)\cong\prod_PV’$, as well as $U\otimes V\cong K^{(I\times P)}$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V,U’\otimes V’)\cong\prod_{I\times P}(U’\otimes V’)$.

Now both $U’$ and $\prod_PV’$ are vector spaces, so free $K$-modules, and hence Mittag-Leffler. It follows that
$$ \prod_IU’\otimes\prod_PV’ \rightarrowtail
\prod_I(U’\otimes\prod_PV’) \rightarrowtail
\prod_{I\times P}(U’\otimes V’) $$
as required.

Comment: But they are not finite dimensional in my case unfortunately so this so not I guess the correct answer . This is the theorem proved after the definition of $\lambda$ in the book. but how this will help me?

Comment: @Emptymind it still works if $U,U',V,V'$ are Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @Hyperplane I guess I need a proof for this

Comment: @Emptymind A proof would really just be that if you have orthonormal bases as described in Andrew's answer, then $E_{ij} ⊗ F_{qp}$ is an orthonormal basis of the tensor product. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces

Comment: @Hyperplane I still did not get why we need an orthonormal basis, where will we use the orthonormality condition in the proof?

Comment: What is the meaning of $R^{(I)}$?

Comment: But I think the book did not mention mittag Leffler module before I think

Comment: $R^{(I)}$ means the free $R$-module with a basis indexed by $I$, or alternatively maps $f\colon I\to R$ with only finitely many $f(i)$ non-zero. So $K^{(I)}$ is a $K$-vector space with basis $e_i$ for $i\in I$.

Comment: The first part of the edit was more of a general setting, explaining that this is a somewhat special situation that $\lambda$ is injective. All one needs is the proof of the relevant property for vector spaces. That proof is not hard; the trick is noting that this property is enough.

Comment: @Emptymind Hilbert spaces are pretty much by definition equipped with orthonormal bases. In infinite dimensional spaces, orthonormal bases are completely different from Hamel bases.

Comment: I do not understand why we will have $\mathrm{Hom}(U,U’)\cong\prod_IU’,$ could you provide a proof for this please?

Comment: @Hyperplane I am asking why we need orthonormality in our proof?

Comment: @AndrewHubery is my equation # $(3)$ correct?

Comment: A linear map $K^{(I)}\to U’$ is determined by its images on a basis, which can be arbitrary, so any function $I\to U’$, so we get $(U’)^{I}=\prod_IU’$.

Comment: Your point (1) is already insufficient. A general element of the tensor product is a finite sum of such ‘pure’ tensors, so $f_1\otimes g_1+\cdots+f_n\otimes g_n$. It is not enough to check injectivity just on pure tensors.

Comment: In your third line , what do you mean by “sending the other basis vector to zero” is not u_i are all the basis vectors of U as we are in the finite dimensional case

Comment: I meant that $E_{ji}$ sends $u_i\mapsto u’_j$ and $u_r\mapsto0$ for $r\neq i$.

Comment: Should the indices of u & v be different as I am writing in equation 1?

Comment: I thought originally this was just a typo, but you made a comment about it later. I used a consistent ordering of U before V in my answer. If you wish to swap one or more tensors around, you may, and this will not affect the argument.

Comment: Why you are naming the basis $E_{ji}$ and not $E_{ij}$?

Comment: ... because it sends $u_i$ to $u'_j$. The elementary matrix $E_{12}$ sends the basis vector $e_2$ to $e_1$.

Comment: it is not very clear for me the importance of the last line in the proof, can you please  explain this to me?

Comment: The first injection is $(\prod_I U’)\otimes N\rightarrowtail\prod_I(U’\otimes N)$ for $N=\prod_PV’$. The second comes from $U’\otimes(\prod_PV’)\rightarrowtail\prod_P(U’\otimes V’)$.

Comment: Why you need the commutativity of $R$ in the Mittag Leffler property?

Comment: Is Every vector space is a free module whether the vector space is finite or infinite dimensional? if so, is the basis also finite in case of infinite dimensional vector spaces? if so, why?

Comment: I guess commutativity of $R$ is not needed. Every vector space has a basis (using Zorn’s Lemma), so is free. Each basis has the same cardinality (which is then the dimension of the space, so finite dimensional iff finite basis). Two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension (so bases of the same cardinality).

Comment: In your last paragraph, in the following part "Now both $U’$ and $\prod_PV’$" why you are not using the product sign beside $U'$ also?

Comment: I answered this already in a previous comment, when I explained the two injections.