# Why we need an orthonormal basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Prove that $\lambda$ is injective.

Here is the definition of the linear map $\lambda$:

Let $f: U \to U'$ and $g: V \to V'$ be linear maps. We define their tensor product $f \otimes g: U \otimes V \to U' \otimes V'$ by

$$(f \otimes g)( u \otimes v) = f(u) \otimes g(v)$$ for all $u \in U$ and $v \in V.$ This gives rise to a linear map

$\lambda: \operatorname{Hom}(U, U') \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(V, V') \to \operatorname{Hom}(V \otimes U, U' \otimes V')$ defined by $$(\lambda (f \otimes g))(v \otimes u) = f(u) \otimes g(v).$$

**Here is an answer given to me here [What happens if $(f_1\otimes g_1)(u_1 \otimes v_1) = (f_2 \otimes g_2)(u_2 \otimes v_2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634232/what-happens-if-f-1-otimes-g-1u-1-otimes-v-1-f-2-otimes-g-2u-2-otim) :**

***But I do not understand:***

1- why we need an orthonormal basis in the solution? where exactly are we using this idea?

2- What exactly the definition of a Mittag Leffler Module?

Could anyone clarify this to me please?

Comment: In my answer to your previous question I gave you one definition of a Mittag-Leffler module: it is a module $M$ such that, for every family of modules $N_p$, the natural map $M\otimes\prod N_p\to\prod M\otimes N_p)$ is injective. This was just for context.

Comment: I showed that every free module satisfies this condition, which is all you need for vector spaces, and then showed how your problem is solved by using this result twice.

Comment: You don’t need an orthonormal basis, and it doesn’t even make sense to talk about them in this general setting.

Comment: @AndrewHubery how did this definition help us in the proof?

Comment: @AndrewHubery it was not clear for me how did we use this result twice? could you please clarify this (maybe there in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We DON'T "need" an orthonormal basis but it simplifies the calculation.
If $v_1$,$v_2$, $v_3$, ...,$v_n$ is an orthonormal basis and v is any vector then $v= a_1v_1+ a_2v_2+ a_3v_3+ ...+ a_nv_n$ where $a_i$ is the dot product of $v_i$ and $v$.

Comment: It satisfies what part exactly of the calculation? I do not quite understand the general idea of the solution given in the other link, can you please explain to me the general idea of the solution? also what is the importance of using the Mittag Leffler Module?